# accuracy altered after updating scikit learn version

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation

I was working on svm cross validation technique for a text classification problem and I got a good accuracy, after upgrading to latest version of scikit learn I observed drop in the accuracy.

I was not sure why this happens with the version changes.

Initial version details

scikit learn - 0.14.1
numpy- 1.8.2
scipy- 0.13.3

Updated to :

scikit learn - 0.15.2
numpy- 1.9.1
scipy- 0.13.3

Rest of my code working same.I observed this issue only with the cross validation technique.

Any Idea?

Here's my code:

```
def classPrediction():
    train_keywordsList=[]
    labelsList=[]

    #For Binary Classification
    with open('datainput.txt','r') as factive:
        readlines=factive.read().splitlines(False)

    for line in readlines:
        train_keywordsList.append(line.split(',')[0])
        labelsList.append(line.split(',')[1])

    #Using SVM
    sv=Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()), ('svm', LinearSVC())])

    train_numpyarray= numpy.asarray(train_keywordsList)

    label_numpyarray = numpy.asarray(labelsList)

    scores= cross_validation.cross_val_score(sv,
                                             train_numpyarray,
                                             label_numpyarray,
                                             cv=5)

    print scores
    acc=  scores.mean()

    return acc
```

Each row in input file contains keyword followed by it's class.

Comment: Can you please share your code or at least say which algorithms you are using? It might be that default parameters changed, though we try to avoid that.

Comment: What kind of drop are we talking about?

Comment: In older version i got an accuracy of 72%.After updating to latest version I am getting 61% accuracy,